# Reference on Curie-Weiss model

Tags: resource-recommendations, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions, ising-model, mean-field-theory

I am looking for a reference on the Curie-Weiss model and mean-field approximation.

**Model.**
Consider the Curie-Weiss model with the following Hamiltonian:
\begin{align*}
H = - \frac{J}{2N} \sum_{i \neq j} S_{i} S_{j} - h \sum_{i} S_{i},
\end{align*}
where $N$ is the number of sites ($i,j=1,2,\ldots,N$), and $S_{i} = \pm 1$ is a spin of site $i$. Also, $J \in \mathbb{R}_{++}$ and $h \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then, we define the partition function:
\begin{align*}
Z = \sum_{S} \exp\left\{\frac{\beta J}{2N} \left(\sum_{i}\sum_{j}S_{i}S_{j} - \sum_{i} S_{i}^{2}\right) - \beta h \sum_{i} S_{i}
\right\},
\end{align*}
where $S=(S_{1},\ldots,S_{N}) \in \{\pm 1\}^{N}$ is a spin configuration and $\beta > 0$ is the inverse temperature. Note that $S_{i}^{2}=1$ for each $i$.

We compute $Z$ in the limit of $N \to \infty$ to see the equivalence of this model to the mean-field approximation.

**Question.**
I am looking for a reference that uses the following approach: (i) We represent $Z$, using Dirac's $\delta$ function, (ii) rewrite the $\delta$ function, using the Fourier integral representation:
$$\delta(k) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\mathrm{i} k x} dx$$

and then (iii) evaluate the integral (thus, $Z$) by the saddle-point method. The first-order condition for the saddle-point method coincides with the self-consistency equation, which characterizes the mean-field approximation.

I'd appreciate any references (books, papers, etc.). If you know several references, please let me know more than one. Thank you.

**Remark.**
I understand the "Hubbard-Stratonovich" approach. That is, (i) we simplify the content of the exponential by the Gaussian integral and (ii) evaluate the integral by the saddle-point method. The first-order condition for the saddle-point method coincides with the self-consistency equation.

P.S.
I am neither a physics student nor a computer science student. Sorry if I have missed some basic references.